# Strange email login issue?

Tags: support, login, email

I changed my email address in Apple.SE's profile settings. But when I log in now, it still requires me to use my old email address.

I'm using SE's own login, no fancy social media connections. I also verified the new email in the link they sent me. When I view my email settings now, it shows the new email address, but logging from a new incognito browser (no stored cookies), my old email is still required.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I assume you're using Stack Exchange's own login (not Google or Facebook)?

Comment: yeah, SE login, no fancy social media connections stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/

Comment: and i verified the new email in the link they sent me. when i view my email settings now, it shows the new email address. but logging from an new incognito browser (no stored cookies), my old email is still required

Comment: I guess you have to wait for SE staffs to check this issue. Just now, there seems a possible disruption on SE's chat servers. I don't know if it affected some other services.

Answer (score 3):

The email address in your preferences is what we'd use to send you email (for example, notifications about unread inbox messages). It is not the same as the credentials you use to log into your account.

You can add another credential by going to the [Add Login](/users/login-add) page. Once you have that done, you can also remove the old credential by going to the "My Logins" section of [your profile settings](/users/edit/current)